# How does OffLiberty.com parse links to get files?

Tags: php, parsing, mp3

Anybody any idea how they do it? I currently use OffLiberty.com to parse Mixcloud links to get the raw MP3 URL for use in a custom HTML5 player for iOS compatibility, I was just wondering if anyone knew how exactly their process works, so I could create something similar that would 'cut out the middleman' so to speak, so my end-user wouldn't have to go to an external site to get a link to the MP3 for the mix they want to post. Just a thought really, not terribly important if it couldn't be done, but it would be a nice touch :)

Anybody any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that **I'm against content scraping** and **you should ask those website permission** to scrap their MP3 URLs. Else, if I was them, I'd block you right now and *ad vitam æternam*.

Anyway, you can parse its HTML using [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

For example :

```
<?php
// just so you don't see parse errors
$internal_errors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);     
// initialize the document
$doc = new DomDocument();
// load a page
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.mixcloud.com/LaidBackRadio/le-motel-on-the-road/');
// initialize XPATH for the document
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
// span with "data-preview-url" seems to contain MP3 url
// we request them inside a DomNodeList http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php
$mp3 = $xpath->query('//span[@data-preview-url]');

foreach($mp3 as $m){
      // we print the attribute value 
    echo $m->attributes->getNamedItem('data-preview-url')->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
libxml_use_internal_errors($internal_errors);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll give that a go when i'm updating that particular project. :)

So there's no confusion, the project I was working on was for a DJ, who hosted HIS music on MixCloud. So any content scraping was done for his music only, and with his permission. :)